# How does Private VPN (like IPVanish) prevent ISPs from monitoring my internet traffic?

Tags: networking, vpn, internet, modem, isp

I've recently purchased [IPVanish](https://www.ipvanish.com/) subscription due to the concern of NSA snooping.

My home network is set up like following

> Computers => Router => ISP Modem (Spectrum)

Now I am worried that ISP would monitor my traffic since all my internet goes through ISPs modem first.

Suppose that I am browsing a website after connecting to a VPN and post a message on ISPs website. Can't Spectrum figure out that it was "I" who posted the message by comparing VPN IP and my outbound packets going through ISPs modem?

Comment: Please kindly let me know, if this question belongs elsewhere and where to post it. thanks!

Comment: Do you know how a VPN works? You tunnel all traffic to the vpn, so the only traffic the ISP can see, is encrypted traffic to a single address your vpn

Comment: @Ramhound The part I don't get is that, to connect to a VPN, shouldn't that connection first go through ISP so that ISP can figure out which VPN I am connecting to? Maybe I should read about VPN more...

Comment: Yes: Your ISP knows your connected to a vpn but traffic to and from the vpn is encrypted

Comment: @Ramhound So in my example in the question, if I posted on their forum via VPN, *theoretically*, ISP can figure out who it was since ISP track the IP of the VPN I connected to?